# How to declare a variable that persists subroutines

Tags: varnish-vcl, fastly

During the recv subroutine I am currently changing my backend to another backend to handle the request, I need to declare a variable that will hold the value for the first/original backend that it was set to, so that when the request is restarted, I can then assign the backend back to this.

I can't just use the name for the backend and simply assign it back as I need it to be dynamic, storing it in a variable seems like the simplest solution but I can't seem to find any information on how this can be achieved through subroutines/ restarts.

If not possible are there any other solutions I could try to achieve this? Probably not possible from what I understand but even the ability to access an array of the backends defined and picking the first one would suffice, I just cant rely on naming the backend to assign it back.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to declare a variable as a `BACKEND` type (which is what `req.backend` returns).

See [this 'Fastly Fiddle' example](https://fiddle.fastlydemo.net/fiddle/8bb8dc1f) that demonstrates you'll get a compiler error of:

> Expected variable type, one of: BOOL, INTEGER, FLOAT, TIME, RTIME, IP or STRING

There also isn't any way to get a list of available backends via VCL either.

Additionally you would need to *hardcode* the backend value (i.e. you need to explicitly know what backends are defined from the VCL perspective) as trying to store a backend into a header or variable will convert it to a STRING type representation (such as `6kLtu7NicmMs0DtKsuite9--F_origin_0`).

This means even if you were able to parse the actual `F_origin_0` backend from the string you wouldn't be able to assign it as a value to `req.backend` as that expects the value to be of type `BACKEND` (and VCL doesn't provide a way, AFAIK, to convert a string into that type).